# Finding Path of File from a string

Tags: c#

I am getting list of startup applications, and wants to get only Path of application running at startup. The list of startup application also contain the parameter passed to the application, which are in different pattern; examples are

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe /onboot
>
> "C:\Program Files\Process Hacker 2\ProcessHacker.exe" -hide
>
> "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe" /MONITOR
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-startup-window /prefetch:5
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\GlassWire\glasswire.exe" -hide
>
> C:\Program Files\IDT\WDM\sttray64.exe

I am trying to use following regex

```
Regex.Matches(input, "([a-zA-Z]*:[\\[a-zA-Z0-9 .]*]*)");
```

Kindly guide me how can I extract only application path ignoring all the parameters and other startup commands.

Comment: Why don't you use string operations? Like for example split with "/" and take first then split with "-" and take first and ... all parameters have markers.

Comment: @Emad there is a chance of missing some splitter, which may later causes issues

Comment: Since in windows most or all the executables have ".exe" extension then you can try finding ".exe " (.exe and an extra space) and then extract the path leaving the parameters.

Comment: Does Path.GetDirectoryName not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple approach:

```
string cmd = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GlassWire\\glasswire.exe\" -hide";

int index = cmd.ToLower().LastIndexOf(".exe");
string path = cmd.Substring(0, index+4);
index = path.IndexOf("\"");
if (index >= 0)
path = path.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: what about `"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GlassWire\\glasswire.exe\" -hide.exe";` ?

Comment: in that case `IndexOf(".exe")` can be used instead of `LastIndexOf(".exe")`

Comment: I mean this is not a generic solution, because one of the directory in path may be like "C:\Internet.executable\setup.exe" then `IndexOf` will also not work.

Comment: yes, I know, but as long as it serves the purpose I think it is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Since the expected input list will contains list of executable files, all are having the `.exe` extension, we can make use of that extension here By suing `.Substring()` method of String class. Sample usage will be like this:

```
 List<string> inputMessageStr = PopulateList(); // method that returns list of strings
 List<string> listofExePaths= inputMessageStr.Select(x=> x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(".exe") + 4)).ToList();
```

Comment: Though unlikely, there might be some executable files with extensions other than .exe for example ".com". Also windows allows executing other file types to be opened by windows. I think this is a good idea but not a robust general solution.

Comment: @Emad: thanks for the valuable point, let me check for some `robust general solution` and update the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases which can break the normal method of finding the complete executable path form a given string.
Simply finding `".exe"` won't work in general case. Atleast one space will separate the actual complete executable path from the parameters.

Note: This solution is based on assumption that the executable would be present on its intended path. Since, OP is having a list of paths of application running at startup this assumption holds.

```
public string GetPathOnly(string strSource)
{
    //removing all the '"' double quote characters
    strSource.Trim( new Char[] {'"'} );

    int i;
    string strExecutablePath = "";
    for(i = 0; i < strSource.Length; ++i)
    {
        if(strSource[i] == ' ')
        {
            if(File.Exists(strExecutablePath))
            {
                return strExecutablePath;
            }               
        }
        strExecutablePath.Insert(strExecutablePath.Length, strSource[i]);
    }

    if(File.Exists(strExecutablePath))
    {
        return strExecutablePath;
    }

    return "";  // no actual executable path found.
}
```